# <bound method ... at 0x000001A55FB96580>

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a couple of dataclasses and an abstract class that manipulates those classes. Eventually, the *my_class_handler* types could be dealing with say: json, xml or sqlite files as concrete instance types.

Can someone please explain to me what this message means?

```
<bound method my_class_handler.class_name of <__main__.my_class_handler object at 0x000001A55FB96580>>
```

Here's the source code that generates the error for me.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class column:
  name: str
  heading: str

@dataclass
class my_class:
  class_name: str
  class_description: str
  columns: List[column]
  
class iclass_handler(ABC):  
  @abstractmethod
  def class_name(self) -> str:
    pass
  
  @abstractmethod
  def class_name(self, value: str):
    pass
  
class my_class_handler(iclass_handler):
  obj: my_class

  def __init__(self):
    self.obj = my_class("test-class", "", None)
  
  def class_name(self) -> str:
    return self.obj.class_names
  
  def class_name(self, value: str):
    if (value != self.obj.class_name):
      self.obj.class_name = value
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  handler = my_class_handler()
  print(handler.class_name)
```

If this is not the proper way of doing this, please point me in the direction where I might learn the proper way.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: It means you're printing a reference to a method, not *calling* the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@khelwood pointed out the answer to the original question. Thanks

As for the @property approach, I tried that and was having nothing but problems and couldn't find any useful examples of inherited properties so I just rewrote the function to take an additional parameter:

```
# I'm working from memory here but I believe this is the jist...
def class_name(self, new_value: str = None) -> str:
  if (new_value is None)
    return self.obj.class_name

  if (isinstance(new_value, str)):
    if (new_value != self.obj.class_name):
      self.obj.class_name = new_value

  return None
```

Anyhow, I have since refactored and have completely removed the whole class_name() method as a result of a redesign that dropped the whole concept of data-handlers.

Thanks again for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not allow overloading like Java, so remove methods that overlap.

Comment: But it won’t complain about it either:  last man wins.  OP really needs to avoid writing Java in Python, that way lies nothing but misery.  In this getter/setter approach, the Python solution is @property, but typically only after a real need for non-direct access is shown.